# How to turn screen off with 1 button but not locked with admin privilege

Tags: android

am kind of new to android so am doing some small app like this to get used to android
I looked up for solution on internet and create a functional app using DevicePolicyManager, but it alway lock the device using admin privilege, so i cant use fingerprint or face recognization to unlock the phone

is there any other method to just turn off the screen as when i click power button?
(not like dim the screen, i found some post like that on internet)

Answer (score 6):

Below Android Pie (API 28) you have two options:

1. Fake lock
2. Root

With the fake lock option, you show a fullscreen black overlay and change the user's screen timeout to 5 seconds (Android has a minimum screen timeout value, which is up to the manufacturer to set; it can be as high as 15 seconds). Once the screen turns off, you set the timeout back to what the user had set and remove the overlay.

With root, you can just send a KEYCODE_POWER KeyEvent as `su`:

```
input keyevent 26
```

Android Pie introduces an accessibility action to turn off the screen. If the device is running Pie, you can use an AccessibilityService to run

```
performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_LOCK_SCREEN);
```

Comment: my phone is pixel xl with android 9 on it, so it mean i can use the second solution right?

Comment: Right. Just look up how to create an AccessibilityService and you'll be set.

Comment: thank you, but at the moment, there is not many devices with android 9, mostly android 8

Comment: @TheWanderer I cant believe more people haven't up-voted this.

Comment: @ng.newbie - time matters, now such possibility is more popular as working on most devices ;)