# Android API for Screen Lock

Tags: android

I recently got onto [Microsoft Launcher for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.launcher&hl=en_US). I really want to know how it allows users to lock the screen with a double tap. What API does it use in Android for Screen Lock ? I have not found any such API for Android which exposes the methods for screen lock.

Please note I am referring to screen lock and **not a device lock that can only be opened with a password** like [over here](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/creating-a-lock-screen-device-app-for-android-4ec6576b92e0).

Is it part of the accessibility suite ? Asking because I had to provide accessibility permission for the app. I had asked this question before but I got an answer that it was not possible with the recent APIs. So how can Microsoft Launcher do it ? It is not using any tricks, like turning the brightness to 0 and waiting for a timeout.

Comment: am also faced this kind of problems

Answer (score 0):

More information can be found at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52903731/7134737). And also [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#GLOBAL_ACTION_LOCK_SCREEN). Hope it helps.